# combine multiple workbook tables to one table on another workbook using vba

Tags: vba, excel, newrow

I am wondering how I can copy the contents from all my workbooks called "Table1" (besides Headers), and Paste to a similarly formatted table called "Table2" on a Master workbook.

Here is the code I've been using to update the 3200 workbooks, I am hoping to use this template again.

I only want to copy the rows that are used (not headers), then add the next table's values to the bottom of the table.

"Table1" on each workbook logs some information every time the Workbook is Saved. I would like the Master "theFILE 1.1.xlsm" to have a Master table ("Table2") on sheet Master Edits.

```
Sub Macro2() 

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim sFile As String
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim FileName1 As String
Dim FileName2 As String
Dim wksSource As Worksheet
Const scWkbSourceName As String = "theFILE 1.1.xlsm"

Set wkbSource = Workbooks(scWkbSourceName)
Set wksSource = wkbSource.Sheets("Sheet1") ' Replace Sheet1 with the sheet name

Const wsOriginalBook As String = "theFILE 1.1.xlsm"
Const sPath As String = "E:\theFILES\"

SourceRow = 5

Dim tbl As ListObject
Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("Table2")
Dim newrow As ListRow
Set newrow = tbl.ListRows.Add


Do While Cells(SourceRow, "D").Value <> ""

Sheets("Sheet1").Select

FileName1 = wksSource.Range("A" & SourceRow).Value
FileName2 = wksSource.Range("K" & SourceRow).Value

sFile = sPath & FileName1 & "\" & FileName2 & ".xlsm"

Set wb = Workbooks.Open(sFile)
'''Enter Code for Copy/Paste Tables 

Sheets("EDITS").Visible = True
Sheets("EDITS").Select
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.Select
'need to omit the header
Selection.Copy

Windows("theFILE 1.1.xlsm").Activate
Sheets("Master Edits").Select
Range("Table2[DATES]").Select
With newrow

    ActiveSheet.Paste

End With

Windows("wb").Activate
Sheets("EDITS").Visible = False

Windows("theFILE 1.1.xlsm").Activate
Sheets("Sheet1").Select



'''CLOSE WORKBOOK W/O BEFORE SAVE
Application.EnableEvents = False
ActiveWorkbook.Save
ActiveWorkbook.Close
Application.EnableEvents = True

SourceRow = SourceRow + 1 ' Move down 1 row for source sheet

Loop

End Sub
```

My problem is that I don't want the Headers. I need to add new rows for the next table's data.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The [`DataBodyRange`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.listobject.databodyrange) of a `ListObject` excludes the headers. Use that instead of `ListObject.Range`.

Comment: @BigBen after trying your recomendation I get a "Run-Time error '438' Object doesn't support this property or method"

Comment: What is the new line you are using?

Comment: @BigBen     'ActiveSheet.DataBodyRange("Table1").Range.Select'

Comment: Not like that... `ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").DataBodyRange.Select` - although you probably don't need to `Select` anything.

Comment: @BigBen That works. how do I have it add new rows to the bottom of the table for the next table? as of now it wants to paste on top of the pre-existing values.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180460/discussion-between-bigben-and-kenny).